# How to replace NA Data using a regression?

Tags: linear-regression

My dataset contains some stocks and some bitcoin titles.
I would like to replace NA data (normal stocks are not traded on sat. and sun.) using a regression on the stock itself. 
How can i do this?

Comment: What you try exactly to do and what way/software you try to accomplish the imputation ? How does your data look ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the column with missing values as your target.

Remove rows where your target is null.

Train a regression model that predicts your target using the rest of your features.

Replace missing values with this regression model's predictions.